# Embassy: will it be demolished?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

**Question #1:**

If embassy build in colonial province, will it be destroyed once provinces separate into the colony?

**Question #2:**

If I build embassy in the colony which is on the beach: will it be ever dismantled?

It shouldn't, right? As you will always border with the see.

**Question #3:**

Will I get money back if building is dismantled?

**Question #4**

If embassy is built on the border, and border changes, will it be dismantled?
I believe so, just would like to confirm..

Thanks.

Comment: I thought it never gets dismantled as long as you control the province. Curious for someone to check this

Comment: There's no requirement for the Embassy to border another nation (you may be thinking of the March). Building something on the coast doesn't guarantee a border with another nation, unless there is another nation with a coast in the same sea province

Comment: The only answer I know for sure is to #3: no refunds :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question #1:**

I don't *think* it will be destroyed, but rather will be transferred to the "new" colonial nation (giving *them* the extra diplomat). But in either case, you definitely won't control it yourself.

> Provinces that you are planning on selling, colonial provinces that haven't yet become a colonial nation, and other provinces that you are likely to lose are of course not a good place to build new buildings.

[Source](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Buildings#Building_strategy)

**Question #2:**

Firstly, there's no requirement for the Embassy to border another nation. You may be thinking of the March, another unique building used for defence. Building something on the coast doesn't guarantee a border with another nation, unless there is another nation with a coast in the same sea province. Viable provinces will be highlighted when trying to build something that has requirements like this.

> Also note that a province which shares a crossing with a foreign province, is still able to have a March in it.
>   [Source](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Buildings#List_of_unique_buildings)

**Question #3:**

As Richard ten Bring mentions, there are no refunds for buildings that are dismantled

**Question #4:**

Any building that no longer meets the requirements will be dismantled.

> Note that if a building no longer meet the requirements (e.g. a March no longer borders another nation), then that building will be dismantled.

[Source](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Buildings#List_of_unique_buildings)